# How to know the stored procedure parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to populate my MSSQL database, so, I will run some procedures with random data. I have to get the parameters of every SP. How I can do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you query `sys.objects` & `sys.parameters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it with simple query -

```
SELECT p.name
FROM   sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.parameters p ON  p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.[name] = 'stored_proc_name' AND o.[type] = 'P'
```

Comment: What if I can't access to sys.object?

Comment: Then you have to create metadata table yourself and query that table. I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: OR you can create view and grant permission to it for querying.